# how to build multithreaded supported UI using C#(WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

how to build multithreaded supported UI using C# ? At runtime I'm changing my values through UI and those values are getting passed to already running threads in backed code ? Please share if someone has any code example or small project

One UI thread and it's intreacting at backend running threads in server.

Comment: This question is rather broad and generic. I'm sure there will be resources out there if you search Google.

Comment: It's not even clear if you're referring to multiple UI threads, or just multiple regular threads and one UI thread. If you're talking about the later, then you just have to make sure to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` and `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` whenever you wanna do something that affects the UI from another thread.

Answer (score -1):

Similar questions use the [BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) as shown on these answers:

- [Updating UI Thread Using BackgroundWorker in C# Form Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404710)
- [How to Update GUI with BackgroundWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590)